# How to detect a button click in a QTableView rows cell

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtableview, qpushbutton

I was able to insert `PushButton` in a `QtableView` cell.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableView, QPushButton, QAbstractItemView
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("experiment")
tab = QTableView()
sti = QStandardItemModel()
for idx in range(0,3):
    sti.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)) for i in range(4)])
    tab.setModel(sti)
    tab.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
    tab.setIndexWidget(sti.index(idx, 3), QPushButton("button"))
tab.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can i check / detect with cell button was pressed ?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect the clicked signal of the button:

```
from functools import partial
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTableView, QPushButton, QAbstractItemView


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.setStyle("experiment")
tab = QTableView()
tab.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
sti = QStandardItemModel()
tab.setModel(sti)


def on_clicked(index):
    print("clicked", index)


for idx in range(0, 3):
    sti.appendRow([QStandardItem(str(i)) for i in range(4)])
    btn = QPushButton("button")
    btn.clicked.connect(partial(on_clicked, idx))
    tab.setIndexWidget(sti.index(idx, 3), btn)

tab.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: thank you. That use of partial was nice, appreciated.